# Windows-7 cannot resolve a Samba share via the .local domain name (but can resolve for TCP/IP)

Tags: windows-7, networking, samba, bonjour, zeroconf

I have a Linux Samba server and a Windows-7 computer running on a local network. I installed Avahi on the server and Apple's Bonjour (version 2) on the Windows computer.

The Windows computer can resolve the server's address `myserver.local` for TCP/IP communication, such as `ping` or ssh connections. But it's not able to see or find the the server in the list of shares. Also typing `\\myserver.local\share` doesn't find it. Using it with the IP address as in `\\1.2.3.4\share` works. So apparently the problem is when converting the name to its address for the purpose of working with shares.

I tried to test it with `nslookup myserver.local`, it prints

```
Server: <my provider's DNS server name>
Address: <my provider's DNS server address>
```

and fails with `Non-existent domain`.

Does this point in the right direction? Is it possible to somehow add resolving the `.local` domain when working with this kind of services? Or what else could I do to debug the issue?

Comment: I'd look at the Windows side hosts file and look for syntax and misconfiguration in that file.

Comment: If you open Windows Explorer and type in the UNC path, \\myserver.local, do you see the share listed there?  If not, you have a misconfiguration on the SAMBA side or in your authentication mechanisms.  Your statement that it works via IP but not via DNS name smacks of Kerberos issues--but that assumes you're using Kerberos in the first place and are requiring it in your SAMBA config.  On Windows, when Kerberos fails or is not used, NTLM is tried.  Kerberos requires DNS so you may be seeing Kerberos rejection using hostname where NTLM is working via IP -- a packet capture would be definitive.